# Convert prepared layout to bitmap and save as image in file

Tags: android, file, view, bitmap

I need to save my prepared layout to image file in external memory

For now I've tried to get my layout, enable drawing cache, pass to bitmap and save in file

```
LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.to_send, null);
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap returnedBitmap;
    if (view.getMeasuredHeight() <= 0) {
        view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        returnedBitmap.recycle();
        Canvas c = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
        view.draw(c);
    }
    else {
        returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);
    }
    //Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
    File fPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File f = new File(fPath + "Send.png");
    try {
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream strm = new FileOutputStream(f);
        returnedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, strm);
        strm.close();
        //content.invalidate();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting some error? Does the program not save the file?

Comment: Look at this example shows just what you want to do. https://github.com/erikcaffrey/API-Github-MaterialDesign-OPI-Test

Comment: it doesn't get right bitmap, it saves nothing to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if somebody meets the same problem. Here what solved my problem. I just needed to get Layout after it was created in Activity

```
RelativeLayout shareLayout = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loveSpace);
shareLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
shareLayout.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = shareLayout.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
```