# How can I save an XML layout resource to an image?

Tags: android, xml

I want to be able to save a 1000x1000 .png image from a layout xml I created. I've found samples online of people saving already displayed views into a .png file, but I can't find any sample code for creating an image from a layout that's not currently being displayed. I *could* just save what's being shown on the screen, because the image being created is very similar, but I don't want layout/resolution to be determined by device size/layout/orientation; I want the image to always be saved the same on every device. I'm fairly new to Android, and I've spent several hours trying to figure out how to do this, but couldn't find anything. This is the xml code for saveable_image_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="1000px"
    android:layout_height="1000px"
    android:id="@+id/sil_main">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500px">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sil_quote_text"
            android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="Sample text 1"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500px">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sil_person_text"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="Sample text 2"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I try to save it to an image like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saveable_image_layout, null);
LinearLayout layout = view.findViewById(R.id.sil_main);

Bitmap bitmap = layout.getDrawingCache();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
layout.draw(canvas);

try {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "img-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

    Log.v(LOG_TAG, file.toString());

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I end up with the error,

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isMutable()' on a null object reference

So I'm guessing the inflater.inflate() call is returning null, but I'm not sure why. Am I going about this all wrong? Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: You gotta see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908117/convert-prepared-layout-to-bitmap-and-save-as-image-in-file This might help :)

Comment: @WijaySharma I can't use those solutions since they just call findViewById() but I can't use that since the inflate() call returns null. edit: or rather, I don't think it's returning null, but I can't operate on the view object it returns

Comment: Why are you guessing, please confirm it is returning null. Since finsViewById is working, obviously it's not returning null. Also I suspect the findViewById is returning null, because the view itself is the layout. There is no need to call findViewById. Lastly, I suspect that nothing will work untill the view is measured.

Comment: Since it's not on-screen, you first have to `measure()` and `layout()` the `View` you're trying to capture.

Comment: @MikeM. This ended up being what worked. But in the end, I actually decided to scrap the method I was using entirely, and create a custom view that overrides onMeasure. The benefit of this is I can dynamically layout where the textviews are, and even make the exported image taller/shorter depending on how much info is in the text view.

Comment: Cool. Oh, I don't know how I missed the answer below, but I just repeated what they showed, only ten hours later. Whoops. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. I didn't mark it as accepted answer until after your comment, cause I ended up not entirely using the solution, though they technically are the correct answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have not enabled drawing cache try to add the following code before you call `getDrawingCache()`

```
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    // this is the important code :)
    // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null
    layout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)); 

    layout.layout(0, 0, layout.getMeasuredWidth(), layout.getMeasuredHeight());
    layout.buildDrawingCache(true);
```

hope that helps.